# Can I get the table id of a file uploaded earlier in the same function?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set the parent_id of images that are going to get uploaded using a loop to the id of an image I uploaded earlier in the function. I could just make a query to the database but I was wondering if there's a better solution.

```
$image = new Image();
$image->name = $title;
$image->description = $description;
$image->user_id = $userId;
$image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

$image->save();
```

Comment: What does the code for storing the parent image look like?

Comment: I've added the code. Essentially, I wonder if I can get the id of $image after the save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hehe, that's an easy one. After you called `save()` on a model, the identifier column set by `$primaryKey` (which is `id` by default) will be populated automatically. So you can simply access `$image->id` in your case.

To test it, just add `dd($image);` right after `$image->save();` and have a look!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.